# Read json array and print the values using vba

Tags: excel, vba, jscript

i have a json object that has a json array. I need to iterate array and print the values. I am using excel [vba].I am very new to VBA. Requesting anyone to help me out.

```
Set sr= CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") 
sr.Language = "JScript"
Set Retval = MyScript.Eval("(" + newString + ")") 
MsgBox Retval.Earth.Fruits(0).name
```

when i execute the above piece i am getting 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.

I need to iterate all the names under Fruit

Comment: my newString will hold : newString will hold :
    {
    "Earth":
{
"Fruits":
[
{
"name":"Mango"
},
{
"name":"Apple"
},
.....
]
},
}

Answer (score 1):

I would use a json parser e.g. jsonconverter.bas as can use with 64bit and 32bit and doesn't represent the same security risk as scriptControl.

Jsonconverter.bas: Download raw code from [here](http://%20https//github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called jsonConverter . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Your json object is a dictionary with an inner dictionary `Earth` containing a collection `Fruits` (where `Fruits` is the key). The items in the collection are dictionaries with keys of `"name"` and values are the *fruits*. The `[]` denotes collection and `{}` dictionary.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String, json As Object, item As Object
    s = "{""Earth"":{""Fruits"":[{""name"":""Mango""},{""name"":""Apple""},{""name"":""Banana""}]}}"
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
    For Each item In json("Earth")("Fruits")
        Debug.Print item("name")
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Example with regex:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "{""Earth"":{""Fruits"":[{""name"":""Mango""},{""name"":""Apple""},{""name"":""Banana""}]}}"
    PrintMatches s
End Sub
Public Sub PrintMatches(ByVal s As String)
    Dim i As Long, matches As Object, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = """name"":""(.*?)"""
        If .test(s) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
                Debug.Print matches(i).SubMatches(0)
            Next i
        Else
            Debug.Print "No matches"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the Swift reply.... As per my organization policy I am not allowed to use unapproved items. I came across same solution but I am not supposed to use that... Any other way.

Comment: Are you aware of the risks of using scriptControl?! That aside... yes you could use regex or split.

Comment: regex example added

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON is just a code module you import into your project - no additional dll etc.  If your company policy would prefer you to use a scriptcontrol over VBA-JSON then that's crazy.  ScriptControl has potentially huge security issues.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Out of curiosity, what kind of security issues are known with ScriptControl? Do you have some links, maybe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you `Eval` script in the ScriptControl, it doesn't run in the context of the browser sandbox, so it has access to your whole PC.  That means creating (eg) a new Scripting.FileSystemObject and reading or deleting files.  For example:  http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html

Comment: @TimWilliams: Ah, ok, that's obvious, thx. I only use it from VBA, so there isn't a browser sandbox at all.